# dbListTable function error

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am trying to set up a MySQL database in R. I've installed RMySQL and set up a connection successfully. I was able to use the `dbWriteTable()` function successfully as well, but when I try to use `dbListTables()` it gives me an error saying

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbListTables’ for signature ‘"missing"`

Can anyone shed some light on this? 
Heres the code:

```
#Install and load Quandl package
install.packages("Quandl")
library(Quandl)

#Install and load SQL package
install.packages("RMySQL")
library(RMySQL)

#Authenicate API key
Quandl.api_key("________")

#Load top 10 biggest Healthcare compaines in Fortune 500 according to 
#http://fortune.com/2015/06/20/fortune-500-biggest-healthcare-companies/
CVS <- Quandl("WIKI/CVS")
McKesson <- Quandl("WIKI/MCK")
UnitedHealthGroup <- Quandl("WIKI/UNH")
AmerisourceBergern <- Quandl("WIKI/ABC")
ExpressScriptsHolding <- Quandl("WIKI/ESRX")
CardinalHealth <- Quandl("WIKI/CAH")
Walgreens <- Quandl("WIKI/WBA")
Johnson_Johnson <- Quandl("WIKI/JNJ")
Anthem <- Quandl("WIKI/ANTM")
Aetna <- Quandl("WIKI/AET")

con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
                user = 'root',
                password = 'password',
                dbname = 'mysql')

dbWriteTable(con, value = Aetna, name =  "Aetna")
dbListTables()
```

Comment: Not unless we see your actual code.

Comment: @hrbrmstr added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what I was doing wrong. I was not providing the connection variable `con` to the `dbListTables()` function. I tried `dbListTables(con)` and it works just fine.